# Eigenvalues of triangular block matrix 2

Tags: matrices

I need a way for compute the eigenvalues of these block matrix
\begin{equation}Acc=\begin{bmatrix}
        A & I \\
        D & 0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}\end{equation}
Where:

- $A$ is a generic $n \times n$ matrix with know eigenvalues
- $D$ is a diagonal  $n \times n$ matrix
- $I$ is the identity $n \times n$ matrix
- $0$ is the null $n \times n$ matrix

I would a closed form from the eigenvalues of $Acc$ and the eigenvalues of $A$ and $D$

If can be helpful, we can consider first the case where $A$ is too diagonal

For example let be consider

- $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
          3 & 0  \\
          0 & 5\\
          \end{bmatrix}$$ the eigenvalues are 3 and 5
- $$D=\begin{bmatrix}
          7 & 0  \\
          0 & 9\\
          \end{bmatrix}$$ the eigenvalues are 7 and 9
- I is the indent matrix $2\times2$
- $0$ is the null matrix $2\times2$

The eigenvalues of Acc are $4.5414,-1.5414,6.4051,-1.4051$

There exist a relation, linear or non linear, from 3,5,7,9, or such other parameters of the matrix A and D, and the eigenvalues of $Acc$
(This questions it was resolved from Pierpaolo Vivo Thanks a lot:-) )

I thought that it is simple pass from the case where A is diagonal to the case where A is a generic matrix

Now WE consider this reformulated problem

Again
$$Acc=\begin{bmatrix}
        A & I  \\
        D & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

- $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 2 & 3 \\
      11 & 5 & 6 \\
       7 & 8 & 9 \\
          \end{bmatrix}$$ the eigenvalues of A are $$17.0245; -1.0123 + 1.2010i; -1.0123 - 1.2010i$$
- $$D=\begin{bmatrix}
          1 & 0 & 0 \\
          0 & 3 & 0\\
         0 & 0 & 7 \\
          \end{bmatrix}$$ the eigenvalues are 1,3 and 7
- I is the indent matrix $3\times3$
- $0$ is the null matrix $3\times3$

The eigenvalues of $Acc$ are $$ 17.3027;  -2.2586 + 1.0499i;  -2.2586 - 1.0499i;   1.7965;   0.5996;  -0.1816 $$

Comment: If $A$ is diagonal too, then the problem decouples into $n$ separate instances of finding eigenvalues of a $(^{*}_{*}\,{}^1_0)$ matrix.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to write $A_{CC}-z I$ and compute its determinant using the formulas for the determinant of a block matrix, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices ?

Comment: Following Pierpaolo Vivo's excellent suggestion: we have
$$Acc-zI_{2n}=\begin{bmatrix}A-zI_n & I_n \\D & -zI_n\end{bmatrix}$$
(where we've used subscripts to indicate the size of the identity matrices). Since $D$ and $-zI_n$ commute, one of the identities from the link P.V. provided (third from the bottom in that section) gives
$$\det(Acc-zI_{2n}) = \det\big( (A-zI_n)(-zI_n) - I_nD\big) = \det (-zA + z^2I_n - D).$$ It's not clear to me that a general formula follows from this; however, it should be helpful in practice.

Comment: Becouse this problem come from an control problem and n is too large is not helpful.
I have already found this formula but it don't help me.

Comment: I would a closed form from the eigenvalues of Acc and the eigenvalues of A and D

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sorry but I don't understand! How can I decouple the matrix for find the eigenvalues????

Comment: @Luca. Could you please clarify what you mean by 'a closed form from the eigenvalues of $A_{CC}$ *and* the eigenvalues of $A$ and $D$'? What do you exactly assume to know, and what do you want to compute?

Comment: @Pierpaolo Vivo I mean that I would a relation between the eigenvalues of Acc and the eigenvalues of A and D.

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo I have improve the question with an exsample

Answer (score 0):

Combining my hint and Greg's solution (using your initial notation, not the notation in the example you added),
$$
\det(Acc-zI_{2n}) = \det\big( (A-zI_n)(-zI_n) - I_nD\big) = \det (-zA + z^2I_n - D)=\prod_{i=1}^n (-z a_i+z^2-d_i)\ ,
$$
where $a_i$ are eigenvalues of $A$ and $d_i$ are the eigenvalue of $D$. Equating to $0$ and solving for $z$, we have that the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $A_{CC}$ are
$$
\lambda_i=\left(\frac{1}{2}(a_i\pm\sqrt{a_i^2+4 d_i})\right)\,\qquad i=1,\ldots,n\ .
$$
Specializing to your example, where $a_i=\{3,5\}$ and $d_i=\{7,9\}$, we obtain
$$
\lambda_1=(1/2)(3+\sqrt{9+28})\approx 4.54138...
$$
$$
\lambda_2=(1/2)(3-\sqrt{9+28})\approx -1.54138...
$$
$$
\lambda_3=(1/2)(5+\sqrt{25+36})\approx 6.40512...
$$
$$
\lambda_4=(1/2)(5-\sqrt{25+36})\approx -1.40512...
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot @PierpaoloVivo.
But if A is not diagonal Can you generalize this formula??  
For me it is very important the case where A is not diagunal

Comment: I thought that it is simple pass from the case where A is diagonal to the case where A is  a generic matrix

Comment: It should work for a generic matrix $A$. Now if the answer was useful, don't forget to accept it :-)

Comment: @PierpaoloVivoSorry but it not work when A is a generic matrix. Now I have rewrite the question

Comment: Surely if you resolve the question where A is generic I quote you in my master thesis